# EF Core - Modify realations without loading entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was trying to implement a function that will let a user like a comment. If the user has already liked it, it can't be liked again and vice versa.
This is what it looks like:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<CommentResponse>> LikeComment(LikeComment like)
    {
        if (like.HasNullProperty())
            return BadRequest("Missing properties!");
        var comment = await commentService.GetCommentWithLikes((int) like.CommentId);
        if(comment is null)
            return NotFound($"No comment with id {like.CommentId} was found");
        try
        {
            var userId = User.GetUserID();
            comment = await commentService.LikeComment(comment, userId, (bool)like.Liked);
            return comment is not null ? Ok(comment.GetCommentResponse((bool)like.Liked)) : StatusCode(304);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Error while trying to {((bool)like.Liked ? "like" : "dislike")} comment");
        }
    }
```

Relevant functions:

```
    public async Task<Comment> GetCommentWithLikes(int id) => await blogContext.Comments.IncludeLikes().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    public static IQueryable<Comment> IncludeLikes(this IQueryable<Comment> source)
        => source.Select(x => new Comment
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleId = x.ArticleId,
            CreatedById = x.CreatedById,
            CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt, 
            Likes = x.LikedBy.Count,
            Text = x.Text,
        });
```

And the main like logic:

```
    public async Task<Comment> LikeComment(Comment comment, string userId, bool liked)
    {
        var user = new User { Id = userId };
        var hasLiked = await blogContext.Comments.Where(x => x.Id == comment.Id && x.LikedBy.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync() is not null;
        Action action = null;
        if (!hasLiked && liked)
        {
            action = () => comment.LikedBy.Add(user);
            comment.LikedBy = new List<User>();
            comment.Likes++;
        }
        else if (hasLiked && !liked)
        {
            action = () => comment.LikedBy.Remove(user);
            comment.LikedBy = new List<User> { user };
            comment.Likes--;
        }
        if (action is null)
            return null;
        blogContext.Attach(user);
        blogContext.Attach(comment);
        action();
        await blogContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return comment;
    }
```

The idea was to not load the whole likedBy relation, but still notify EF Core that i have added or removed one user. Therefore i modify the Comment, then attach it so EF Core tracks the changes to the likedBy relation. Interestingly, it works fine when liking a comment. However, when disliking, i get an rrror that the comment is already attached. Using .AsNoTracking() in the GetCommentsWithLikes function didn't help.

> The instance of entity type 'Comment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

This is the comment passed to the like func when linking (works):[image]

This is the one when disliking (only diff is the like count...):[image]

And this is it right before the failing attach: [image]

Maybe someone knows the reason for this behaviour and can help me or suggest a different approach :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Using .AsNoTracking() in the GetCommentsWithLikes function didn't help

Due to the used projection, that function is already implicitly no tracking. It is the following call

```
var hasLiked = await blogContext.Comments
    .Where(x => x.Id == comment.Id && x.LikedBy.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync() is not null;
```

which is adding a `Comment` instance to the change tracker when the result is not null.

Since you don't need that instance and are just checking for existence, use the following instead which doesn't involve entity instances, but pure server side query:

```
var hasLiked = await blogContext.Comments
    .AnyAsync(x => x.Id == comment.Id && x.LikedBy.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id));
```